# IIS 8 Url Rewrite to Ignore Directory

Tags: url, iis, url-rewriting, url-routing, iis-8

I'm trying to setup a IIS 8 Website. I want to ignore the last directory of a typed in url, but not to remove it instead just ignore it. The directory name could be anything

**Explanation**

Website URL : https://mywebsite.com

The site has a directory named `/stores`, which has a complete website. 
The website will use the non-existent directory `/somename` in the URL to render the website properly.

If i type in `https://mywebsite.com/stores/somestore` obviously i will get `404 Not Found` as the directory `somestore` does not exist inside `stores`

How can i write an IIS Rule to ignore that last part of the URL directory which does not exist but to also keep it in the URL's so it can be used by PHP to render the page properly.

Kind of like Facebook, where a profile is access by adding `/profilename` to the URL.

**NOTE :** I cant use URL Parameters for this due to some technical clashes.

Feel free to update the this questions title, i'm not sure if its entirely correct.

Comment: I still couldn't understand your requirement clearly. In my opinion, if you don't want to show the 404 error page, you could define a custom 404 error page.  If the server wants to return the 404 error, you could show your own 404 php page instead of the default 404 page.

Comment: @BrandoZhang no i am not talking about a custom 404 page. Basically if you look at the address bar on stackoverflow right now after the folder `/questions` there is a supposedly directory named `ThisQuestionsId` (55762513). But in the actual server is there a folder with that name? I assume not. I want to know how this is achieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Basically if you look at the address bar on stackoverflow right now after the folder /questions there is a supposedly directory named ThisQuestionsId (55762513). But in the actual server is there a folder with that name? I assume not. I want to know how this is achieved.

As far as if you want to achieve the url format like stackoverflow by using IIS url rewrite.

I suggest you could refer to below rule.

It will rewrite the https://mywebsite.com/question/55553 to https://mywebsite.com/question.php?id=55553

That means you could write the logic inside the question.php page to select data and show it according to the query string id's value.

```
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
                <rule name="RewriteUserFriendlyURL1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^question/([^/]+)/?$" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="question.php?id={R:1}" />
                </rule>

    </rules>
  </rewrite>
```

Comment: You answers seems to work for one file only, do you know why the other content in the root path is not being included, like images, css and javascript they don't seem to show up?

Comment: After playing around with your answer a bit a figured out the problem. Thanks